# MySQL delete trigger not updating other table column

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update, calculated-columns, cascading-deletes

I have a products table that has a `quantity_on_hand` column which needs to be updated when a transaction is inserted / updated / deleted. In the insert table I have reduced the field by the qty in the transaction and in update I have reduced and added as per the `NEW` and `OLD` values in the transaction. In the `DELETE` trigger I simply have added the stock based on the `OLD` transaction values.

The `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers are working fine but the `DELETE` trigger is neither updating properly nor generating any error! Here is the code:

**INSERT TRIGGER (Working)**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_stockout_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `stockout` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE stockin SET qoh = qoh - NEW.qty WHERE id_stockin = NEW.id_stockin;
END;
$$
```

**UPDATE TRIGGER (Working)**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_stockout_au` AFTER UPDATE ON `stockout` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE stockin SET qoh = qoh + OLD.qty WHERE id_stockin = OLD.id_stockin;
UPDATE stockin SET qoh = qoh - NEW.qty WHERE id_stockin = NEW.id_stockin;
END;
$$
```

**DELETE TRIGGER which is NOT WORKING as intended**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_stockout_ad` AFTER DELETE ON `stockout` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE stockin SET qoh = qoh + OLD.qty WHERE id_stockin = OLD.id_stockin;
END;
$$
```

Can anybody please tell me what I am missing here? Please note there is no syntax error and the code is creating the triggers fine and there are also no errors shown when the trigger is executing and MySQL is not reporting any error code! I have tried changing from `AFTER` to `BEFORE` but the issue is the same. The value in `qoh` remains the same after deleting a row!

This issue is still persisting. I tested it on other MySQL database server on a cPanel based environment running MySQL 5.5. The environment on my development server and this production server is more or less the same and the issue is the same.
Variable_name   Value
innodb_version  1.1.8
version 5.5.22-cll
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)

**Update:** The DELETE trigger is *performing perfectly fine* when the delete command is being given directly on the `stockout` table i.e. `delete from stockout where id_stockout=12`. However, if we are deleting a row on a table that has a cascade delete on this `stockout` table then the cascade delete is working but the delete trigger on `stockout` is not being executed. E.g. table `salesinv_det_items` has its primary key as foreign key in `stockout` and the relationship is cascade. Whenever we delete a row in `salesinv_det_items` the corresponding foreign key rows in `stockout` are deleted but the delete trigger for `stockout` is not executed.

Comment: Variable_name Value
innodb_version 1.1.8
protocol_version 10
slave_type_conversions 
version 5.5.22-cll
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os Linux

Comment: "Currently, cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers." This bug is killing my database. Thay added the info in the manual and done nothing to fix it.

Comment: @ficiek Same here! I dont know what caused them to provide triggers and foreign keys when they cant provide the minimum that the rest of the world has! And they compare themselves with MS SQL, Sybase, DB2 etc. And it is now years and still no fix! Another few years and it will be a decade of living with that bug! The industry should highlight these vulnerabilities so that it would cause them some monetary loss in business to force them invest resources to resolve this bug. Otherwise I think they are living off fine without fixing it for so many years now. Its a shame really!

Answer (score 2):

The OP wrote:

> **Answer:** 
>   MySQL has a bug since release of 5.0 and that is not yet resolved to this date that does not trigger a trigger from a foreign key cascade operation. 
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>
> **It says:** *Currently, cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers.*
>
> Amazing as it may seem but it is true!
>
> The answer then is NOT to have foreign keys that cascade but to write triggers to do that work instead.

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)